# Edit Text and CheckBox checking

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I currently have 2 checkboxes with an edit text field beside them.  There are 4 checkboxes total and I have the logic to check each one and uncheck others if they are checked (almost radio button style).  These 2 however could both be checked if they have values in the edit text fields.

However, if the `EditText` field (which is set to numeric) has a value of 0 or is blank I want it to uncheck the check box and set the value to 0.

Here is the code I have to do this

```
    if (etBase.getText().toString() == "0" || etBase.getText().toString() == ""){
        etBase.setText("0");
        cbBase.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        cbBase.setChecked(true);
    }
    if (etField.getText().toString() == "" || etField.getText().toString() == "0"){
        etField.setText("0");
        cbField.setChecked(false);
    } else {
        cbField.setChecked(true);
    }
```

As it sits right now I default the two fields to be "0" when it starts.  When this logic runs, it is setting both checkboxes to checked.

I must be missing something here.

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare `Strings`. Use `String#equals` instead

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.  I'm trying to apply the programming rules I learned long ago and I guess certain things do change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare string, you must use `.equals()` function. ( Or `.compareTo()` but that's no the today's deal)

Ex :

```
if (etBase.getText().equals("0") || etBase.getText().equals("")){
  ...
}
```

`var1 == var2` is used to get if these both variable have the same object